# jump to line via letters instead of relative numbers

Tags: line-numbers, jump

I currently use relative numbers to jump from my current line to another one.

But since typing letters is easier then numbers, i wanted to know if there is a way to replace the line numbers with letters so every line has a letter and i can press for example "space" "e" to jump to the line with "e" next to it.

And if this doesnt exist, any tips on how to create this plugin or why this is a stupid idea are appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Vi/Vim SE. Well, if you ask experienced/advanced Vim users how often they need to use relative line jumps most will probably tell you "not often". There's such a powerful set of native commands for navigation/edits (e.g. text object motions) that it doesn't come up so often that they'd really need what you are requesting. I know that's not a straight answer ("Go become an advanced user!" ;) but I think it's something worth being aware of. Cheers.

Comment: But how do they do things across multiple lines or move to a specific one? I know how to operate on paragraphs, search, or jump to matching braces, but these rarely get me precisely where i want to go.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion

Comment: You say search rarely gets you precisely where you want to go...it should do precisely that. Are your regex skills decent? Either way if you sometimes get to the right line but wrong column `f`, `F`, `t`, `T` are good commands to follow up with.

Comment: Someone just posted this FYI @MarsRover: https://github.com/skamsie/vim-lineletters/

Comment: @BLayer You made me curious, how do you navigate in between lines? I use relative line numbers a lot and it works well for me, as I've trained to hit the numbers correctly, mostly :) If there are more advanced ways to to this, I'd like to know. BR

Comment: It's more about using all available tools  rather than having a secret weapon. `^`, `G`, `H`,`M`,`L`,`[[/]]`,`[/]`,`(/)`, `f/F/t/T`,`|`,`w`,`B`, etc., etc.  If I'm going someplace I've already been it could just be jump to mark since I'm in the habit of dropping marks if I think I might need to come back. Of course, I use `/` if nothing else gets  me all the way there. I'll occasionally use relative numbers, too. (I said "not often" not "never". Don't mean to give the impression those are bad.) Then there are all my personal custom commands/mappings/functions...but you get the point.

Comment: (cont.) Note that I'm talking about getting to a certain column of a certain line not just a certain line. (Otherwise commands like `B` and `f` that I mention wouldn't make any sense.)  Oh, and I use `*` and `#` a lot. And `Ctrl-O` and `Ctrl-B` and `Ctrl-U`. And `%`. And... :)

Comment: @MartinTournoij `vim-lineletters`? Wow. What a find. Looks like it's right on the nose.

Comment: It was posted to /r/vim just yesterday @BLayer; I'm going to guess it was somehow inspired by this question (here or posted on another platform?)

Comment: using vim-easymotion, `<leader><leader>j` puts letters on the lines below, and similarly for upwards.